# How to pass multiple variables from jsp to servlet using ajax in javascript

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm new to `jsp` and `ajax`.

How to pass multiple variables to servlet using  `xmlhttp.open("GET",servlet,false);` from `ajax` in `jsp`.

I have two Select boxes like name and a phone no, I need to send that selected values to servlet, in servlet I pass address,city like multiple details to the jsp using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use GET, you can pass the variables by URL encode it and add them to the url request, like this :

```
var url = "/path/to/myservlet";
var params = "somevariable=somevalue&anothervariable=anothervalue";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
```

If you have long datas to pass, using POST is the preferred way, here is an example of such code :

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/path/to/myservlet";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(params);
```

You will be able to read those datas in your servlet `HttpServletRequest` using the `getParameter(String name)` method.

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: thanks for ur reply (xmlhttp.open("GET","ClientDetails"+ "?client=" + documnt.getElementById("client").value+ "&contact=" + documnt.getElementById("contact").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { 
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("address").value =xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("city").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        } 
      This is my script please check is it right or wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : "<portlet:resourceURL id='URL'/>",
        data : {
            "A":value,
            "B":Value
        },type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
        }
```

Comment: thank you ,i hv another qstn . how can i receive multiple response from the servlet in ajax success

Comment: You can add all the response in json object in servlet and pass it to View and parse the Json object

Comment: if u dont mind please give one example for that,thank u

Comment: sorry for replying late, I am having much work, I will do it for u, when I am free, plz accept :)